# Filtering with python for searching in database

Tags: python, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

Iam new to python and iam coding a small webapp to search in a database.

I have tried this code but it doesnt work. It only work when put a max of 3 colum to search like lieu, cote , categorie for example.

I tried to split them using elif but it doesnt give me the exact matches.

Is there a way to correct this so i can find the exact matches when i fill all the input ?

For example this is a vieuw when i search for lieu : sion and annee : 1799 its works but when i add signataire : derivaz it doesnt find anything.

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cR9g.png)
Updates : It also works when i had categorie, it seems that when it has to search for signataire or sujet who have multiple colum it get confused.

Here is my last shot :

'''

```
def search_results(search):

    results = []
    lieu = search.data['Lieu']
    annee = search.data['Annee']
    signataire = search.data['Signataire']
    cote = search.data['Cote']
    sujet = search.data['Sujet']
    categorie = search.data['Categorie']

    if search.data['Lieu'] or search.data['Annee'] or search.data['Cote'] or 
search.data['Categorie'] or search.data['Signataire'] or search.data['Sujet']:

        qry = db_session.query(Cote).filter(or_(
            Cote.lieu.contains(lieu), Cote.annee.contains(annee), 
Cote.cote.contains(cote),
            Cote.categorie.contains(categorie), 
Cote.signataire_nom.contains(signataire),
            Cote.signataire_titre.contains(signataire),Cote.sujet_1.contains(sujet), 
Cote.sujet_2.contains(sujet), Cote.sujet_3.contains(sujet)))

        results = qry.all()
```

'''

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share some data or the structure of the table you try to query. This will help people who answer.

Comment: Voilà @Stereo i had some more details

Answer (score 1):

From you code I understand that you are using flask-sqlalchemy. Try the following code. it might help you.

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
conditions = [
    Cote.lieu.contains(lieu),
    Cote.annee.contains(annee), 
    Cote.cote.contains(cote),
    Cote.categorie.contains(categorie), 
    Cote.signataire_nom.contains(signataire),     
    Cote.signataire_titre.contains(signataire),
    Cote.sujet_1.contains(sujet), 
    Cote.sujet_2.contains(sujet), Cote.sujet_3.contains(sujet)
    ]

qry = Cote.query.filter(or_(*conditions))
```